# If $|G|=16$ and $|X|=31$ then an element of $X$ stays stable

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

Let $|G|=16$  which acts on a set $|X|=31$, show that it exist an element of $X$ which remains stable under the group action.

---

I denote $X^G=\{x\in X\mid \forall g\in G, gx=x \}$, we have $|G|=16=2^4$ , $2$ is prime

then by the theorem we get $|X|\equiv |X^G|\mod{2}$

$2$ doesn't divide $31$, so it must be $|X^G|>0$

Can I somehow show that  $|X^G|=1$ ?

Comment: I think the exercise wants *at least one* which you already showed. E.g. let $G$ be a cyclic group which acts as cycling $16$ elements, then $15$ are fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $|X|\equiv |X^G|\mod 2$, then $|X^G|$ must be odd just like $|X|$. Therefore $|X^G|\not=0$, done. But you cannot show $|X^G|=1$. For example, $|X^G|=31$ is possible for the trivial action of $G$. (In fact, one can show that $|X^G|$ can possibly be any odd value $\le 31$.)